# putExtra in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Имеется Главное Активити ,которая переходит на другое Активити где находится TabLayout,ну и фрагменты понятное дело.Мне нужно передать значения типа int в фрагмент допустим One ,как это реализовать?

> Главное Активити

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityG.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("P",number1);
                    intent.putExtra("R",number2);
                    startActivity(intent);`

> Активити фрагмент

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), " ");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), " ");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), " ");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

> фрагмент

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    P = Integer.parseInt(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("P"));
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), P, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во фрагменты значения передаётся так же как и в активити через `Bundle`:

```
Fragment fr = new MyFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("key", 42);
fr.setArguments(args);
```

Теперь внутри фрагмента получайте данные так:

```
int myInt = getArguments().getInt("key", -1);
```